# Страницы wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Как реализовать в wordpress возможность писать записи в определенные страницы?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Быть может я не понял суть вопроса, но постараюсь ответить. Записи не подчиняются страницам, записи подчиняются рубрикам (категориям). Но можно делать это в ручную. Создаешь страницу и после того как запись опубликована, делаешь на этой странице ссылку на эту запись. Смотри пример ["Станица со ссылками на записи".](http://samodelkin.kz/uroki-wordpress) Получается, что на одной странице собраны все записи сайта.

Comment: Спасибо. Про страницы понял. Записи можно делать в рубриках.

Answer (score 0):

Параметры->Чтения->Указать "Статическая страница"

Comment: Спасибо. Эта информация для меня оказалась тоже нужной!